# Batch file - Control + G

Tags: batch-file, exit, ctrl

I want to add a line (or lines) to my batch file

> if (ctrl + g is pressed) goto end

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET controlg=
ECHO Press control-g to exit
:again
SET "key="
For /F "delims=" %%z In ('Xcopy /W "%~f0" "%~f0" 2^>Nul') Do If Not Defined Key Set "Key=%%z"
SET "key=%key:~-1%"
IF NOT "%key%"=="%controlg%" GOTO again
ECHO now exiting...
ECHO exiting...
GOTO :EOF
```

It's not perfect by any means...There is actually a control-g character being set into the variable, even if it's not being shown. Naturally, that could be placed in the `if not ...` statement, it's just how I do things...

Comment: What I want is different. I am sorry that I didn't show what I want in my question. I used a line `set /p mycmd="Mycmd\>"` and I hope that when I pressed ctrl + g it will show `^g` and goto something.